# Is this Wordpress Critical Error after Upgrade to 5.24.1 serious?

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, error

Upgrading from 5.23.3 to 5.24.1 - I got a critical error after the upgrade. this is what I can find from the wordpress log around the time I ran the upgrade. (wordpress 5.3) The upgrade was successful - not sure if I need to respond to these errors.

```
[06-Apr-2020 18:42:36 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: CRM_Upgrade in /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Service.php on line 120
[06-Apr-2020 18:43:33 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'CRM_Civirules_Utils_Upgrader' not found in /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicoop.civirules/civirules.php:106
Stack trace:
#0 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(286): civirules_civicrm_managed(Array)
#1 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook/WordPress.php(139): CRM_Utils_Hook->runHooks(Array, 'civicrm_managed', 1, Array, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
#2 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php(86): CRM_Utils_Hook_WordPress->invokeViaUF(1, Array, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'civicrm_managed')
#3 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(184): Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher::delegateToUF(Object(Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent), 'hook_civicrm_ma...', Object(Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher))
#4 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event in /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicoop.civirules/civirules.php on line 106
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a regression bug since 5.22.1. Just submitted [PR](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/17004) to core, can you please try upgrading after applying [patch](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/17004.patch)? If the patch works it would be helpful to add your QA results on [PR](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/17004) to help the PR to get merged in next release.

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: I forgot to mention - the upgrade went through even though there was an error.